# Center Align Contents Of A Page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, blogger

I've been trying to center align the `#main` div on a page so far, but I have been unsuccessful.

The page in question is a generic page.

I've been applying the css `margin: 0px auto;`to the `#main` div, but I could not make it center align.

I wanted the content to be center-aligned on large screens, but the floating menubar to be same.  Can anybody help me in achieving this? I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this:

```
#main {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 600px;
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
      text-align: center;
}
```

So simple `HTML` example:

```
<div id="main">
    <span>Simply dummy text</span>
    <span>Simply dummy text</span>
    <span>Simply dummy text</span>
</div>
```

You can't do `width: 100%` because you need to define the width of the element you are centering, not the parent element.

**EDIT:**

I created demo on `jsFiddle.net` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sajmon/j6rbL/)

Comment: works, setthe width to 1321px - actual width of contents, and it did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

The value auto for margins has no effect as long as you don't set a width. As a result of that, you have to set the width of div#main.

Look at the purble box in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/byBxH/).

Comment: do I set the width to 100%? :$

Comment: I set it to 100%, but it's not working still.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you set it to e.g. 600px like in the demo above (see the purple box)?

Comment: thank you for all you help.  Repping both you the the above guy, but will accept the above one as answer, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a problem with your HTML. You applied an ID (`main`) two times in a single page. ID's are unique, i.e. you can only use them ONCE per page. Classes can be used as much as you want.

```
#main {
  width: 1320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
}

.bigpic {
  width: 540px;
  /** and  remove max-width **/
}
```

And don't forget to remove that second ID. It's on the first child of `#main-wrapper` (unfortunate naming)

Comment: that's blogger causing those mess ups :(  Can't really do anything about it :(  WordPress one day I hope :P